# Is their a better way to write this code?

Tags: java

I know that this code does what I need it to do for my assignment but I can't help but feel like there is a much more...refined way to get the same results. Note that the last few outputs should only display if there have been at least 1 number(s) that are greater or less than 0

```
//This program will take an unspecified number of 
//integers, determine how many of those integers are
//positive and how many are negative, and finally
//compute the total and average of the integers.


import java.util.Scanner;

public class exampleWork {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //create a scanner
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    //create a variable to hold the positive integers
    int pos = 0;

    //create a variable to hold the negative integers
    int neg = 0;

    //create a variable to hold the total number of entries
    int total = 0;

    //create a variable to hold the average
    float avg = 0; 

    //create a counter variable
    int count = 0;

  //prompt user to enter integer
   System.out.println("Enter an integer, the input ends if it is 0: ");
    int usrInput = input.nextInt();

        //determine if the number is positive, negative,
        //or zero, and either place in relative variables,
        //or end the loop.
    if (usrInput == 0)
        System.out.print("Only zero was entered");

    while (usrInput != 0) {

            if (usrInput > 0){
            pos++;
            total += usrInput;
            count++;
            System.out.println("Enter an integer, the input ends if it is 0: ");
            usrInput = input.nextInt();


          } if (usrInput < 0){
            neg++;
            total += usrInput;
            count++;
            System.out.println("Enter an integer, the input ends if it is 0: ");
            usrInput = input.nextInt();


           }

        }
    if (count > 0){
    avg = (total / count);
    System.out.println("The number of positives is " + pos);
    System.out.println("The number of negatives is " + neg);
    System.out.println("The total is " + total);
    System.out.println("The average is " + avg);
    }
```

}

}

Comment: leave out the comments about "create a ..." they don't add any value. don't describe what you do, this is what the code should tell already. describe why you do it.

Comment: I was primarily making the notes in that manner because it was a class assignment but It is a good tip to know how notes are expected to be used. Thanks. I was unaware of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You duplicated code inside the two of your main ifs. This extracts them in that part and cleans it up some.

```
while (usrInput != 0) {
    if (usrInput > 0)
        pos++;
    else
        neg++;

    total += usrInput;
    count++;
    System.out.println("Enter an integer, the input ends if it is 0: ");
    usrInput = input.nextInt();
}
```

[Edit of which I just make like 6 XD but now I am done] On some other notes:

- You don't need to keep a running "count", since it can be calculated after the main while loop by adding (pos+neg).
- You are adding extra code to do the first trial.
- You are averaging 2 ints, which makes an int, not a float.
- You dont need to explicitly store the average since it is only used once.

Here it is lessened

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class exampleWork {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //create a scanner
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        //create a variable to hold the positive integers
        int pos = 0;

        //create a variable to hold the negative integers
        int neg = 0;

        //create a variable to hold the total number of entries
        int total = 0;

        while(true) {
            System.out.println("Enter an integer, the input ends if it is 0: ");
            usrInput = input.nextInt();
            if(usrInput==0)
                break;

            if (usrInput > 0)
                pos++;
            else
                neg++;

            total += usrInput;
        }

        int count=pos+neg;
        if (count > 0){
            System.out.println("The number of positives is " + pos);
            System.out.println("The number of negatives is " + neg);
            System.out.println("The total is " + total);
            System.out.println("The average is " + ((float)total / count)); //Not sure if this typecast is correct, it's been a long time since i have worked in java
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems to be a common answer about my code. I want to say that I had tried to do that very early on when writing the code but I was given some type of error *eclipse* when I tried to add the "else" statement within the "when" but I can not remember why.    If I did not run a count how would I get the last few statements to execute?

Comment: I edited it a bunch for other problems, if you're interested. If should answer what you just asked.

Answer (score 0):

Note that most of the two `if` statements are identical, so they can be extracted outside the `if`s instead of duplicated:

```
while (usrInput != 0) {
    total += usrInput;
    count++;

    if (usrInput > 0) {
        pos++;
    } else {
        neg++
    }

    System.out.println("Enter an integer, the input ends if it is 0: ");
    usrInput = input.nextInt();
}
```

Comment: I see! I knew that those two were redundant but I could not think of the way to compile them. Thanks.